# Want to Serialization Json include [JsonIgnore] in sometimes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, serialization, json.net

I have classes that 95% don't want to serialization some negation properties. So I use [JsonIgnore] attributes & Newtonsoft.Json, and it works fine.

However, I have only few methods want to return JSON that includes properties from [JsonIgnore]. How I can do that?

Thank you all

```
public class SubCatalog
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Catalog")]
    public int CatalogId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual  Catalog Catalog { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual IList<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

With this method, I want to include all properties in entity.

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetSubCatalogs(int id)
    {
        var list = _uow.SubCatalogs.GetByCatalogId(id);
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list,
                                               Formatting.Indented,
                                               new JsonSerializerSettings
                                               {
                                                   ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
                                               });

        return new HttpResponseMessage()
        {
            Content = new StringContent(json, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use the IContractResolver

```
public class IncludeIgnored : DefaultContractResolver
{
    private readonly bool _includeIgnored;

    public IncludeIgnored(bool includeIgnored)
    {
        _includeIgnored = includeIgnored;
    }

    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        IList<JsonProperty> properties = base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization);

        foreach (var item in properties)
        {
            item.Ignored = !_includeIgnored;
        }

        return properties;
    }
}
```

Then when you call your serializer

```
var serializedObject= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObject, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new IncludeIgnored(true) });
```

Comment: Small heads up, don't forget to use the same JsonSerializerSettings to deserialize the object again. Otherwise the ignored properties will be included in the JSON, but they will still be ignored while constructing the object.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to implement custom JsonConverter.

override WriteJson method and implement custom serialization there.

```
public class Converter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanRead { get { return false; } }
    public override bool CanWrite { get { return true; } }


    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(SubCatalog);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
          //serialization code here
    }
}
```

Add instance of this converter to `Converters` property of serializer or `JsonSettings`